# PHP 7 include file error - file name is parsed incorrectly

Tags: php, nginx, include, php-7, litespeed

Recently I met a weird error and hope someone can help.
We use `LiteSpeed WebServer` and `Nginx` on top, with `PHP 7.5` and `MySQL 5` (well, WordPress is the framework). It runs well for many days.

Suddenly it goes fatal at this line in different files

`include ("class-xxx.php");`

The error log says

```
[02-Oct-2018 13:04:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'dlass-xxx.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear') in /xxx.php on line N
```

I double checked the code and see that the file name is declared `"class-xxx.php"`, but somehow the server tries to include `"dlass-xxx.php"`, thus it cannot find the file and trigger fatal error.

Solution? I re-upload the file, it works. But then it goes fatal in another file, at similar lines using include.

I notice that the first character in the file name, for example "c", is read incorrectly and shift 1 byte before (or after), so the file name is correct.

Such as

```
include "class-xxx.php" is parsed/read as "dclass-xxx.php"
include "page-xxx.php" is parsed"read as "opage-xxx.php"
...
```

this is very strange. Do anybody know the reason? Is it related to any caching/memory management of `LiteSpeed` or `Nginx` or `PHP 7. ?`

It happens on `PHP 7`. only because if I switch to `PHP 5.6`, the error does not happen.

Hope someone can help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please, provide your question with code.